# Reading a text file of ints and printing it onto the screen

Tags: java

```
        while(kb.hasNext())
        {
           array[i] = kb.nextInt();

           System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
```

I'm reading a text file containing

1 2 3

2 1 3

3 1 2

1 2 3

2 1 3

3 1 2

I'm trying to print it out the same way it is formatted in the text file but I can only print it out like this.

1 2 3 2 1 3 3 1 2 1 2 3 2 1 3 3 1 2

First time asking a question on here so I apologize if it's not clear or poorly worded.

Comment: what is kb in while loop? is it scanner

Comment: diplicate answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104616/using-bufferedreader-to-read-text-file

Comment: Yes, I am using scanner.

Comment: instead of reading int you can directly read whole line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
int count = 0;
while(kb.hasNext()) {
    int i = kb.nextInt();
    if (count++ % 3 == 0) 
        System.out.println(i + " ");
    else 
        System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

or if lines were difference length then

```
while (kb.hasNext ()) {

    String in = kb.nextLine ();

    // either 
    // just print it
    System.out.println(in);

    // or split it and iterate
    String arr[] = in.split (" ");
    for (String i : arr) {
       System.out.print(i + " ");
    } 
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Comment: if (count++ % 3)  it will not return true. compiler error

Comment: @TipuSultan Sorry too much haste

Comment: I guess that would work. But what if each line has a different length?

Comment: @D.Moua  it is java not C and C++

Comment: Better to use `hasNextInt` instead of `hasNext` in first case.

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks alot. It's printing properly now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.out.println` which will print new line at the end but `System.out.print` just print the line.

Comment: If I use println then it just prints like this. One int per line, but this post is just making it all on one line.

1 
2 
3 
2 
1 
3 
3 
1 
2 
1 
2 
3 
2 
1 
3 
3 
1 
2

Comment: Check @Scray Wombat answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. But this is what I ended up doing.

```
        while (kb.hasNextInt()) 
        {          
           String in = kb.nextLine ();
           System.out.println(in + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
```