# How to detect EOF in Java?

Tags: java, eof

I've tried some ways to detect EOF in my code, but it still not working.
I've tried using BufferedReader, Scanner, and using char u001a to flag the EOF, but still not make any sense to my code.
Here is my last code :

```
    Scanner n=new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    int counter=0;

    while(n.hasNextLine())
    {
        input=n.nextLine();
        char[] charInput=input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if(charInput[i]=='"')
            {
                if(counter%2==0)
                {
                    System.out.print("``");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("''");
                }
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(charInput[i]);
            } 
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

The program supposed to stopped when it's already reached the EOF, but I don't know why, for some reasons it keeps running and result a runtime error.
Please help.
By the way I'm new here, sorry if my question is not really clear to be understood,
Thank you before :)

Comment: What is the Runtime error that you are getting?..

Comment: Also, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104616/using-bufferedreader-to-read-text-file) post on how to read a file using `FileReader` + `BufferedReader`

Comment: I believe the scanner will just return ```null``` instead of an EOF character. That would explain the runtime exception.

Comment: @JornVernee No hasNextLine will check the underlying read for null and return false. His program works as expected on my machine.

Comment: You are reading input from the console (stdin), maybe it behaves strange on your host. Try reading from a file you open.

Comment: how do you run your program? are you actually piping in content from a file or are you just running it without piping in content (and just inputting values by hand into the console)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It keeps running because it hasn't encountered EOF. At end of stream:

1. `read()` returns -1.
2. `read(byte[])` returns -1.
3. `read(byte[], int, int)` returns -1.
4. `readLine()` returns null.
5. `readXXX()` for any other X throws `EOFException`.
6. `Scanner.hasNextXXX()` returns false for any X.
7. `Scanner.nextXXX()` throws `NoSuchElementException` for any X.

Unless you've encountered one of these, your program hasn't encountered end of stream. NB `\u001a` is a Ctrl/z. Not EOF. EOF is not a character value.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that you need to use the corresponding `hasNext...` call, not just `hasNextLine` everywhere, since that will return true if you read the last token with `next` and there's an empty line at the end.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(f); //f is the file object

while(s.hasNext())
{
String ss = s.nextLine();
System.out.println(ss);
}
```

Worked for me

Comment: You should use `hasNextLine()` in conjunction with `nextLine()`, and similarly for the other method pairs.

Answer (score -3):

You can use **try and catch**.

```
Scanner n=new Scanner(System.in);
String input;
int counter=0;
input=n.nextLine();
try{
    while(input!=null)
    { 
        char[] charInput=input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if(charInput[i]=='"')
            {
                if(counter%2==0)
                {
                    System.out.print("``");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("''");
                }
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(charInput[i]);
            } 
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        input=n.nextLine();
    }
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

Here, when you will give **Ctrl+z**, `Scanner.nextLine()` will give you `NoSuchElementException`. **Use this exception as a condition of EOF**. To handle this exception use try and catch.

Comment: Hacky - it ignores the hasNextLine method intended to tell you when input is exhausted.

Comment: Incorrect. `nextLine()` doesn't return null at EOS, it throws `NoSuchElementException`.