# How can i use EOF in java (whitout using file)

Tags: java

In C i do this:

```
int main(){
int N = 0;
while(scanf("%d",&N) != EOF){ // <--- how to do this condition in java?
... Code ...
}
```

My input is some numbers: 10 20 5 9 7 6... and when i hit enter my output is some matrix.

[Print with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1BGK.png)

I know there is another topic, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515937/how-to-detect-eof-in-java), similar to this, but not solve my problem.

Any suggestion?

---

My problem is solved by Elliot, i just do this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {      
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int N = 0;
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);           

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){

            N = (int) scanner.nextDouble();
            ... code ...
          }
      }
```

Working fine.

Comment: Have you any code yet?

Comment: Java isn't `C`, and EOF is usually represented by `-1` in Java.

Comment: You should figure out pretty quickly that you're not using ``scanf`` in java. Start from there and see if you really need something like EOF.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch actually EOF is normally represented by `null`

Comment: @nafas Not with [`InputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29); of course it depends on how you read the File.

Comment: @mrbela, donsen't matter my code, it's running, but my problem is that condition with the while, how can i represent that in java.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I want to pass a line of input, like: 10 20 30 5 9 [enter]. And when i hit enter my code is do stuff. And after this enter, it's supposed to be able to do the same thing again, and again, and again.

Comment: Use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and `while (scanner.hasNextLine())` and `scanner.nextLine()` to operate on lines.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, you solve my problem, put an answer so a can mark as solved.