# java Is there a way to end like C ++ except EOF

Tags: java

EOF is defined for C ++ itself
But if there is no EOF in JAVA?
Sample picture
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reading input till EOF in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927326/reading-input-till-eof-in-java)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515937/how-to-detect-eof-in-java

Comment: @ghosh Scanner is line buffered and parses. That is not exactly the OP's wish: reading a byte or end-of-file.

Comment: We far prefer pasted code rather than screenshots.

Comment: This looks to me like it may be relevant: [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it/6876253)

Answer (score 1):

Java `InputStream#read` will behave exactly so, returning -1 (C/C++) EOF or an other int in the byte range, unsigned as 0 .. 255.

However `String` (with `Reader` and `Writer`) in java is for Unicode text, `char` being a 2-byte UTF16 value. `Input-` and `OutputStream` and `byte` is for binary data, needing some encoding (`Charset`) to convert it to `String`.

```java
    byte[] read(InputStream in) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            baos.write((byte) c); // Cast not needed, as int.
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    String read(InputStream in) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            baos.write((byte) c); // Cast not needed, as int.
        }
        return baos.toString("UTF-8"); // Conversion provided.
    }
```